# Why the order is not preserved when printing something, first with cerr and then cout?

Tags: c++, std

I have g++ version 4.8.4 compiler with **Xubuntu** 14.04. In the midst of my OpenCV code (written in Eclipse CDT), I wrote the following three lines consecutively:

```
/* Some codes here*/
cerr << "No match found. # of false positives: " << falsePositives << endl;
cout << "Press a key to continue..." << endl;
waitKey(0);
```

and here is the result:

```
Press a key to continue...
No match found. # of false positives: 1
/*there is a blank line*/
```

Why the order of those two lines changed at the execution time? There is no parallel code at all in the previous lines but they seems to work like parallel (at the same time).

I know that cerr is not buffered whereas cout is buffered (which means, afaik, cerr is slower compared to cout); however, no matter what, shouldn't the order of execution be changed? And where does that blank line comes from? (probably from one of those endls but which one?)

Can someone explain what is going on those two lines?

Thank you so much.

**EDIT:**
I don't use ubuntu, I use **Xubuntu** 14.04. Sorry for that mistake, my mind was too messy but I think it does not effect the result.
I use Eclipse's provided console to display them. I tried to append std:: prefix to all cout, cerr, endl. The result is same.

The interesting point is that when I just wrote a new file including:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{       
    std::cerr << "No match found. # of false positives: " << 2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press a key to continue..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I got the expected output(first cerr and then cout) by using xfce4-terminal and g++ compiler.

The problem occurs when using Eclipse CDT. I also want to remind all of you that I work on OpenCV.

Chris Dodd's 4th suggestion:

*"your code is actually something other than what you've posted above, and the difference, while seemingly unimportant, is actually crucial."*

Of course my code does contain other than what I typed but there are lots of, I mean lots of computation etc. before those lines. However, there might be relating parts before which I could not realise. Also, I didn't redirected stdout and/or stderr to different devices/files/pipes before those lines at all.

**EDIT 2:**
When I execute the program in the Debug mode of Eclipse CDT, following assembly lines,

*After `cerr` line the followings are executed (as well as other assembly codes of course):*

```
callq 0x403500 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
callq 0x403470 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
callq 0x403770 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
```

*After `cout` line the followings are executed (as well as other assembly codes of course):*

```
callq 0x403500 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
callq 0x403770 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
callq 0x403670 <_ZN2cv7waitKeyEi@plt>
```

and they all give the same error message:

No source available for "std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<<  >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)@plt at 0x403500"

and the process continues with other lines of assembly code without termination.

PS: When I commented out everthing but those two lines, it works as expected. Thus, my conclusion is that, there may be relevant code part before those lines but I couldn't figure them out.

Comment: They are separate streams, so that doesn't surprise me. If the order is important, you could flush to force the output before doing the next message.

Comment: Maybe the compiler reordered the code.  Can you check the assembly to see if that is the case?.  Also I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a39d312254a86bf)

Comment: @NathanOliver It would be incredibly wrong if it did that.

Comment: @Barmar I agree but since the OP is flushing both streams I can't really see what else would cause this.

Comment: One possibility is that your program is completing both writes to the streams before control passes back to the program running the terminal.  The terminal program just sees that data is available on both streams at the same time -- it can't tell which one happened "first" -- and, the terminal program happens to process standard output before standard error.

Comment: @Steven Reasonable assumption, given that the standard out file descriptor is `1` vs standard error at `2`. I'm curious if adding `std::this_thread::yield()` between the calls would make a difference.

Comment: @lcs If that's the problem, yielding would probably seem to "work" in a simple scenario (say, a machine under light load), but there would be no actual guarantee the terminal program would get scheduled to run prior to your application being scheduled again.  Maybe it's better to think of cerr as only for "out-of-band" reporting for errors -- never expect it to actually synchronize with cout.  In the program above, maybe it would be better to treat the error as just normal program output?

Comment: @Steven AFAIK, a shell will connect stdout and stderr of a child process to a single stream when neither is being redirected, which would ensure proper serialization between them.

Comment: @Sneftel I think you're right about standard shells -- although I can't test it right now.  But I can't think of anything else that would really explain the problem, though.  Maybe the original poster is using a non-standard shell?  Or trying to colour errors differently from output (causing it to use two streams)?

Comment: @Steven: He might be seeing this in something like the Eclipse (or some other IDE) Output window / tab. I don't believe that thing is a standard terminal.

Comment: @Steven pored through some source, and it actually goes a lot deeper -- it's `getty` that dups them, not the shell. `xterm` does the same thing, only opening one pipe for the child output and error. But a different output application might not be quite as well-behaved.

Comment: @Sneftel - That's interesting, thanks!  Although I suppose getty could combine them, and the shell could then split them back apart (or, like Zan Lynx points out -- maybe the OP isn't using an actual terminal).  However, I think the important thing is in both Jesper and David's answers -- really, there never was any guarantee that whatever was reading a mix of output and error would read/process them in chronological order.  So although the hypothetical "why" is interesting, the real answer is "you just can't rely on it working that way".

Comment: @lcs Sorry, not using C++11.

Comment: @Zan Lynx is right. I am using Eclipse CDT's console to display them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::cerr` and `std::cout` are different streams and they are not synchronized. 
So you really can't assume anything about how output to both gets shown. In this case, the output happens to be shown before the error.

You *can* rely on the order *within* either stream.

Additionally, `std::cout` is buffered and `std::cerr` is not, and that often causes this kind of problem, but because you are using `std::endl` (which flushes the stream) this doesn't really apply in your case.

Comment: The OP *is* flushing the streams (`std::endl` forces a flush).

Answer (score 2):

The order of those two lines was not changed. However, whatever code produced the output you saw failed to preserve the order in which the output was sent to the two streams. It's possible that it just waited and then read both streams to produce the final output. It's hard to be sure without knowing what your environment looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT is inserting itself into the `cerr` and `cout` streams during the creation of your process. It may echo the `cerr` stream to one of its windows and then write to the intended console. A tee of sorts.

Since it is polling these streams, it is not be possible to synchronize them.  This could explain the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `std::endl` flushes the stream to the underlying device, which mean that the output *cannot* legally be what you describe -- the first `endl` is sequenced before the output to `cout`, so the `cerr` stream *must* be flushed and the output appear on the terminal before the second line is executed.

Which means there are a number of possibilities

- your computer is broken or compiler is buggy (unlikely)
- you've defined `endl` to be something other than `std::endl`, and it doesn't flush (possible if you're trying to be obfuscated)
- you've redirected stdout and/or stderr to different devices/files/pipes and are later combining them, and that later combination step is reordering things.
- your code is actually something other than what you've posted above, and the difference, while seemingly unimportant, is actually crucial.

So if you want a real answer to this question, you need to post and [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you are actually doing.

Comment: Hmm. Certainly the given output to the `cerr` stream should be flushed out before the output to the `cout` stream, but I don't see why that means the output "cannot legally be" as described. They are different streams; what the environment does with them is unknown. It would be perfect normal for the two streams to go to entirely different files. If two different streams are being multiplexed together into terminal output, and both have text waiting when the terminal checks—it can do whatever order it wants, no?

Comment: @Kundor: part of the problem is the OP doesn't say what he's doing with the output to "see" that result.  But while they are different streams, if they are connected to the same underlying device (such as a terminal), the flush guarentees that that device will see the writes in order.  Now that device might be something weird that scrambles the output is some way, but a normal Ubuntu terminal will not.

Comment: AFAIK a flush doesn't force a context switch to any listening processes, so it's perfectly permissible that both flushes will occur before task switching, so that the terminal will see both writes at once. It has no way of knowing which write came first (they are in order within each stream, but don't have timestamps: it's just a stream of text.)

Comment: @Kundor: A flush forces a context switch to the kernel, which handles the write to the device.  If the device isn'y ready to handle the data, it will block the writing thread until it is ready.  A device is not a process, so it isn't 'listening' -- it just is.