# Wrong console output order of cout and cerr

Tags: c++, cout

I would like to output an error when nothing is written into the introduction and the user is able to write an introduction again after the error output.
The problem is that the console outputs are in the wrong order.
Why is it like this and how can i solve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string introduction;
    cout <<"Introduction:" << endl;
    getline(cin,introduction);


     if(introduction.size()==1)
     {
         cerr << "ERROR PLEASE WRITE AN INTRODUCTION!" << endl;
         cerr.flush();
         cout <<"Introduction:" << endl;
         getline(cin,introduction);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
    Introduction:

    Introduction:
    ERROR PLEASE WRITE AN INTRODUCTION!
```

New Edit: editted main into the source code

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned int microseconds;
int main() 
{
    string introduction;
    cout <<"Introduction:" << endl;
    getline(cin,introduction);
    cout << introduction.size()<< endl;

    if(introduction.size()==1)
    {
         cerr << "ERROR PLEASE WRITE AN INTRODUCTION!" << endl;
         microseconds=1000;
         usleep(microseconds);
         cout <<"Introduction:" << endl;
         getline(cin,introduction);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the order change if you redirect stderr from the shell, as in `a.out 2>&1`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. What OS and compiler are you using? Also why are you checking for `introduction.size()==1`?

Comment: @n.m. Windows 10, 64-bit the copiler is Cygwin GCC

Comment: @n.m. checking for this because of that that the user could enter enter and the requirment is that a text has to stay in "introduction".

Comment: @Jan I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Can you try to disable the new console functionality? (see the bottom of this article: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: If the user just hits enter, the size should be zero, not one.

Comment: @n.m. No, through the getline function the size is 1

Comment: @SergeBallesta done

Comment: "through the getline function the size is 1" No, it's 0. Perhaps your standard library is broken?

Comment: @n.m. charriage return counts as 1

Comment: This is a question that should be unasked. Don’t write user prompts to `std::cerr`.

Comment: There's no carriage return. The stream does newline translation so that your program should never see the carriage return. https://ideone.com/58PswW If you see the carriage return, your environment is thoroughly broken.

Comment: @n.m. but thats not the problem.. my problem is the order of output

Comment: There is a similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884578/why-the-order-is-not-preserved-when-printing-something-first-with-cerr-and-then. There is some disagreement whether flushing a stream should cause it to be written before another stream -- see the second answer.

Comment: Your environmentt looks broken. A broken environment is probably broken in more than one way. I have no idea what other deviations from normal behaviours are there. Switch to a different console, a different compiler, or both.

Comment: Regardless of the cause of the problem, it does not make sense to write the message to cerr if you are writing it as part of a "conversation" with the user, which already started on cout. cerr should be used for a separate purpose.

Comment: Output of `endl` writes a '\n' and then calls `flush`, so no need to `flush` after `endl`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The perfect solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned int microseconds;

int main() 
{
    string introduction;
    cout <<"Introduction:" << endl;
    getline(cin,introduction);


    while (introduction.size() == 1) 
    {

        cerr << "ERROR PLEASE WRITE AN INTRODUCTION!" << endl;
        microseconds = 1000;
        usleep(microseconds);
        cerr.flush();
        cout << "Introduction:" << endl;
        getline(cin, introduction);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Perfect* solution? Not really.

Comment: Perhaps it works for you in your broken environment, but it certainly doesn't work in normal non-broken environments. I have tested it on several machines with different compilers and operating systems and it doesn't work on any of them. Hence I have downvoted the answer, so that future visitors won't be misled by it.